# animation in android listview

Tags: android, listview, animation

I am Working on one project in android and i found one issue.any need will be more helpful to me.I want to apply animation to listview like FAN animation in this link.

http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/

here is my code for animation.
 JAVA CODE

```
 animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.push_right_in);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
```

push_right_in.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Comment: You need to create a custom component.

Comment: try this code for apply aniamtion in listview https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: @FrankN.Stein any detail help will be appreciated.